# sublime text User Preference File Rewritten

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, preference

My sublime text user preference file get rewritten.  (user/Preferences.sublime-settings)

I wrote some comments about the settings that I made (So that I can remember next time I look at the user preference file.) But it removed all the comments and reshuffle all the settings. Is it a normal behavior?

Can I keep my comments in the user preference file? I search through stackoverflow and could not find similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behavior (unfortunately), and there is no way around it - it is hard-coded into Sublime. The same behavior exists in Sublime Text 3 as well. The issue has already been [reported](https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues/426) to the unofficial Sublime Text Issues repository, so the community is aware of it, but whether or not Sublime's author takes notice of it and/or fixes it is up to him alone.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that. I wonder what is the reason behind that.

Comment: @user2920692 No idea. None of the other user preference files behave this way, so he must have had a reason, but he has neglected to share it with the rest of us :)

Comment: I guess, I have to go with the workaround suggested in the bug report. I will keep two preference files, one in the ST config folder and other in some other folder with all the comments.

Comment: [Comments were removed](https://plus.google.com/+DouglasCrockfordEsq/posts/RK8qyGVaGSr) by JSON's creator, Douglas Crockford

Comment: @skube yes, there are no comments in "official" JSON files. What's interesting about Sublime's case is that only this file is rewritten to reorganize settings and remove comments - all the other config files, which are also JSON-formatted, allow both single- and multi-line JS comments, and **don't** get rewritten.

Comment: Actually it's not the _only_ file with this behaviour. `Package Control.sublime-settings` is also reorganized/stripped. But yes, most do retain comments.